# Eclipse Android XML Editor Error:The file dose not exist

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have been working on Eclipse classic last version to develop an Android Application and just now it craches and I can't view or write any xml file. 
The error appears while openning the Eclipse is as follow:
Android XML Editor Error:The file dose not exist

here are snapshots of my errors:

[image: Error 1: while openning Eclipse]

[image: Error 2: after openning an XML file]

thank you,

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and solved it by taking following steps
1) Opened a project whose XML file was working correctly.
2) Closed the XML files which were getting error of the previous project.
3) Restarted the Eclipse.

I got this error when I got power failure at my home and don't know what this error means but I fix it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced eclipse main folder with original downloaded and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you open eclipse you will see 3 or 4 .xml files already opened like string.xml etc... close all these files and close your eclipse. Again open eclipse and you will not see this error again.

Answer (score -1):

please Close all the xml files and restart your Eclipse SDK it will solve when the workspace have the more metadata and plugins than you have this type of the error but the easy solution is that you have to close all xml and just restart your SDK